# Limit scope of variables to request

Tags: session, asp-classic, vbscript, request

Is there a way in classic ASP to define variable which will be usable during one request processing but will be discarded after the request is processed?

Session is not good, because I don't want to have the variable defined already for the next request in the session.

Something like:

in some asp file:

```
Request.Variables("key") = 1
```

in other asp file

```
if (Request.Variables("key") <> 0) then    
  Request.Variables("key") = 2
end if
```

etc.

Comment: Can you give us a more concrete example? Edit it into the body of your question since comments are sometimes overlooked by other question readers.

Comment: I have added a small example.

Comment: I fear you're out of luck, such mechanism does not exist. You can just define a session variable in the first asp file, read in the other file and then remove from session making it "one time" value, thus not accessible in the next request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume that by wanting the variable available to all ASP scripts during one request that you mean that the variable needs to be available to one ASP script and all other scripts added using INCLUDE, is that right?

If so, if you create your variable using DIM in the main ASP script before you include the other scripts then it will be accessible to all INCLUDEd scripts too.

For example:

test.asp

```
<%
Dim i
i = 1
Response.Write("A:" & i & "<br>")
%>
<!--#include file="test2.asp"-->
<%
Response.Write("C:" & i & "<br>")
%>
```

test2.asp

```
<%
i = i + 1
Response.Write("B:" & i & "<br>")
%>
```